# ¿Cómo navegar hacia un archivo externo desde mi página con React sin usar React Router?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy armando mi Portfolio con React pero no se como añadir los enlaces a mis proyectos.

La ruta de mi Portfolio es la siguiente:

```
C:\Programación\React\portfolio
```

La del archivo de ejemplo que quiero abrir es esta:

```
file:///C:/Programaci%C3%B3n/Portfolio/index.html
```

En la aplicación de React estoy intentando con esto:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html">Portfolio</a>
```

Para resumir mi pregunta.

¿Cómo navegar hacia otro archivo fuera de la carpeta con React?

Comment: Creo que debes tener esos archivos del portafolio dentro de la carpeta `public` de react

Comment: lamento darte esta información pero no puedes (ni deberías) acceder a ningún directorio de tu servidor fuera de lo que es tu web por una cuestión de seguridad(imagínate si pudiéramos hacer eso, cualquiera podría entrar directamente a tu PC). Si necesitas hacer eso, lo unico que deberías hacer es, como dijo @Pipe  usar tu carpeta _public_(o cualquier otra carpeta publica que tengas en tu servidor)